# NextJS production not refreshing data

Tags: next.js, prisma, production-environment

- when I refresh my localhost page, newly added data to database are visible
- when I refresh my production page, data are not updated (same when deployed)

I cannot found out why data are not reloaded on production. Using NextJS APP folder, Prisma, deployed throw Vercel, Planetscale as database. It loooks like web is a cached. How to make it work?

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getFighters() {
    const fighters = await prisma.fighter.findMany({
        where: {
            fightBlue: null,
            fightRed: null
        }
    });
   
    return fighters;
}

async function UsersPage() {     
    const fighters = await getFighters()

    return (...);
}

export default UsersPage;
```

**update**:
adding

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

helps to reload a data when page is refreshed (F5). It don't reaload a data when I click on link in Navbar. Is this case when I should use some stage management library like Redux?

Comment: Maybe you are using different URI env variables string on local and production

Comment: using same connection string to database. I see same data as in database when I deployed it

Comment: do you already have the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @esthrim no I didnt. Gave up to learn nextjs after this

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently.

Next.js by default statically renders every route, to overcome this behaviour you would need to explicitly declare the component a dynamic one

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

This ensures the component will always be rendered dynamically upon being requested, meaning the Prisma call should run again, fetching new data every time you refresh.

Comment: good, that works much better. Page is rerendered when refreshed. Problem persist (without clicking F5). I have form for creating figher on first page and list of fighters on another one. How to make prisma run when going to the page with a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try revalidatePath and validate parameter of next.js
Here is an example from a sample project

```
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

const baseURL = process.env.BASE_URL

async function getArticles() {
  try {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}home`, {
    next: {
      revalidate: 0,
    },
  });
  const path = baseURL + 'home'
  revalidatePath(path)
  return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

You might want to set validate value to n seconds if you want to cache the data. Setting it to zero means opting out of caching.